# Law of total expectation on product of RVs

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, martingales

I am working through a problem where I wish to claim that:
$$
\mathbb E \left[\prod_{i=0}^n \frac{f(X_i)}{\mathbb E [f(X_i) \ | \ \mathcal F_i]} \right] = \mathbb E \left[\prod_{i=0}^n \frac{f(X_i)}{f(X_i)} \right] = 1.
$$

Is this a valid application? The $X_i$ random variables are not necessarily independent. (of course it would be trivial then)

Comment: What is $\mathcal{F}_i$ in this context.

Comment: A filtration - an increasing sequence of sigma algebras. I don't believe that should affect the question however.

Comment: Well i do think it matters, in particular it matters how $X_i$ is related to $\mathcal{F}_i$. For instance if $X_i$ is $\mathcal{F}_i$ measurable, then the problem is trivial, since we would then have $\mathbb{E}[f(X_i) \: | \: \mathcal{F}_i] = f(X_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_i$ is independent of $\mathcal F_i$ for each $i$  then the left side becomes $\frac {\mathbb E \prod_i {f(x_i)}} {\prod_i \mathbb E f(X_i)}$ which need not be $1$ since $X_i$ are not assumed to be independent.

On the other hand if $(X_i)$ is adapted to $(\mathcal F_i)$ then the equation is obviously true.